# vbnet select inside a select to a dt

Tags: sql, vb.net

I got this little code where I connect to a db, select the data and write the data to a file.

...

```
sqlquery = ("select field1 as Asl, field2 as nCuen , field3 as nfac , "" as contr from [2016cl]")

Using connection As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection("server=" & srvSQL & ";database=" & bdSQL & ";uid=" & usrSQL & ";password=" & pswSQL & ";")
    connection.Open()
    Using comm As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(sqlquery, connection)
        Dim rs As SqlDataReader = comm.ExecuteReader
        Dim dt As DataTable = New DataTable
        dt.Load(rs)

        Call clCreateCSV.CreateCSVFile(dt, strFileNameDiario)
    End Using
    connection.Close()
End Using
```

.....

```
Public Shared Sub CreateCSVFile(dt As DataTable, strFilePath As String)
    Dim sw As New StreamWriter(strFilePath, False, Encoding.UTF8)
    Dim iColCount As Integer = dt.Columns.Count

    For Each dr As DataRow In dt.Rows
        For i As Integer = 0 To iColCount - 1
            If Not Convert.IsDBNull(dr(i)) Then
                sw.Write(dr(i).ToString())
            End If
            If i < iColCount - 1 Then
                sw.Write(";")
            End If
        Next
        sw.Write(sw.NewLine)
    Next
    sw.Close()
End Sub
```

I need to fill 4th value on the select ("" as contr) with field from another table which joins to another middle table.

field3 joins another table on GFac.Gfac2 
the table Gfac joins the 3rd table on CCli.ccli1 --> **this is the one I need on the query**

Could just use inner join but, afaik it would only get the fields that validate the join.

how can i do this, writing **ALL** the data from [2016cl] and the field contr for each one of them if it exists?

Thanks in advance. If you need more info, just ask!

Comment: For me it seems this is a pure sql question. Then why you show all that VB code? Show your tables and how they are related to each other. Show some sample data and the expected result of the query.

Comment: hi @Tim Schmelter, thanks for your time. I'm posting all the code 'cause I don´t know if I should go the sql way and make the query bigger or would be better to just do it programatically.

Comment: of course it will be more efficient to do that with sql, but we have too little informations to help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use LEFT JOIN instead INNER JOIN.

For example:
SELECT * FROM TABLE1 LEFT JOIN TABLE2 ON ...

That query selects ALL rows from TABLE1. If a row in TABLE1 doesn't have a match record in TABLE2, then the TABLE2 fields contains NULL.

Hope that helps.